# How to call `replace-string` with specific strings from code?

Tags: replace

Sometimes I want to replace `[$]` with `\(` and `[/$]` with `\)` either in the region or in the whole buffer. `replace-string` works well for that, except for requiring me to type the strings I want to replace. I would like to call it with these specific strings from an elisp function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

From `replace-string` documentation:

> This function is for interactive use only;
>   in Lisp code use `search-forward` and `replace-match` instead.